# Tensorflow - keras: bad performance for simple curve fitting task

Tags: matlab, regression, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement a very simple one layered MLP for a toy regression problem with one variable (dimension = 1) and one target (dimension = 1). It's a simple curve fitting problem with zero noise.

---

### **Matlab\Deep Learning Toolbox**

Using levenberg-marquardt backpropagation on a MLP with a single hidden layer with 100 neurons and hyperbolic tangent activation I got pretty decent performance with almost zero effort:

**MSE = 7.18e-08**

Plotting the predictions and the targets I get a very precise fitting.

### **Python\Tensorflow\Keras**

With the same network settings I used in matlab there's almost no training. No matter how hard I try to tune the training parameters or switch the optimizer.

**MSE = 0.12900154**

In this case the plot of the predictions is a curve that is not even able to follow the oscillations of the target curve.

I can obtain something better using RELU activations for the hidden layer but we're still far:

**MSE = 0.0582045**

This is the code I used in Python:

```
#  IMPORT LIBRARIES
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


#  IMPORT DATASET FROM CSV FILE, SHUFFLE TRAINING SET 
#  AND MAKE NUMPY ARRAY FOR TRAINING (DATA ARE ALREADY NORMALIZED)
dataset_path = "C:/Users/Rob/Desktop/Learning1.csv"
Learning_Dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_path
                          , comment='\t',sep=","
                          ,skipinitialspace=False)
Learning_Dataset = Learning_Dataset.sample(frac = 1)  # SHUFFLING


test_dataset_path = "C:/Users/Rob/Desktop/Test1.csv"
Test_Dataset = pd.read_csv(test_dataset_path
                          , comment='\t',sep=","
                          ,skipinitialspace=False)


Learning_Target = Learning_Dataset.pop('Target')
Test_Target = Test_Dataset.pop('Target')

Learning_Dataset = np.array(Learning_Dataset,dtype = "float32")
Test_Dataset = np.array(Test_Dataset,dtype = "float32")
Learning_Target = np.array(Learning_Target,dtype = "float32")
Test_Target = np.array(Test_Target,dtype = "float32")





#  DEFINE SIMPLE MLP MODEL
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(inputs)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)




#  TRAIN MODEL
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.001,
                                  rho = 0.9,
                                  momentum = 0.0,
                                  epsilon = 1e-07,
                                  centered = False)
early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100)
model.compile(optimizer = opt,
              loss = 'mse',
              metrics = ['mse'])


model.fit(Learning_Dataset, 
          Learning_Target,  
          epochs=500, 
          validation_split = 0.2, 
          verbose=0, 
          callbacks=[early_stop], 
          shuffle = False, 
          batch_size = 100)




#  INFERENCE AND CHECK ACCURACY
Predictions = model.predict(Test_Dataset)
Predictions = Predictions.reshape(10000)

print(np.square(np.subtract(Test_Target,Predictions)).mean()) #  MSE

plt.plot(Test_Dataset,Test_Target,'o',Test_Dataset,Predictions,'o')
plt.legend(('Target','Model Prediction'))
plt.show()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There may be something that MATLAB does by default that tensorflow doesn't. For instance, did you normalize your inputs, i.e., making sure that they are about zero-mean and the variance is close to one?

Comment: hi @ShanqingCai, yes the data is normalized, shuffled and has no noise or missing values. I did a lot of research and it turned out that there's a lot of posts like this around the web and it seems that the problem is that first order optimizers like the ones implemented in tensorflow/keras are not suited for this kind of tasks with few dimensions. On the other hand levenberg-marquardt optimizer in matlab is great for these tasks. In other words it seems that you cannot fit a simple function like sine with a neural network in tensorflow. It still seems crazy to me but...